# Android accelerotmeter - detecting a person turning

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, motion, degrees

I have started to play with interacting with the accelerometer and had an interesting question.

Is there a way to reliably detect if a user is turning on the spot with the phone - and how much (e.g. degrees)?

I tried looking it up and did not find any useful results (after cutting through all the false positives that come from words like 'turn' and 'rotate').

Maybe I am thinking of the wrong technology for the job (GPS is better?) but I was thinking something that the phone would not have to rely on outside input in order to work.

Imagine the user is standing to form a vertical "axis" around which phone orbits. I would like to detect if the user holding the phone in front of him turned (for example) 90 degrees to the left. Reliability and accuracy of the degrees measured is nice does not have to be high.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in general is no. A user can stand still and turn his phone. If the phone is fixed, then yes, just use the azymuth. I would say it could be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Use gyroscope for this task,Gyroscope gives you the roation around phone phone axis ..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro